# How can I bind a control to a List<string>?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged, catel

Seems like a very basic MVVM question, but when it comes to Catel, I have issues doing it.

- I have a property - registered as it should - which is a List, named Lines.
- I bind it to a ListBox.
- I also have a Button with a command adding a entry to Lines.
- Lines is mapped to a model, and when I check the values of the model, I see it gets updated correctly when adding a value to Lines.

So everything seems to work, except that **my view isn't updating when Lines is modified**.

I tried to solve this by **adding a RaisePropertyChanged("Lines")** in Lines' setter, and in the command that adds a new value to Lines.

It gives something like this for the property:

```
[ViewModelToModel("MyModel", "Lines")]
public List<string> Lines
{
    get { return GetValue<List<string>>(LinesProperty); }
    set
    {
        SetValue(LinesProperty, value);
        RaisePropertyChanged("Lines");
    }
}

public static readonly PropertyData LinesProperty =
    RegisterProperty("Lines", typeof(List<string>), null, (s, e) => {});
```

and this for the command (yes, I have `AddLine = new Command(OnAddLineExecute);` in the viewmodel's constructor):

```
public Command AddLine { get; private set; }
private async void OnAddLineExecute()
{
    // this doesn't seem relevant, but since we're talking async and stuff, that may as well be the issue
    if (!lineCountChecked && Lines.Count >= 4)
    {
        if (await messageService.Show(MainDialogs.LineCountCheck, "Lines count", MessageButton.OKCancel, MessageImage.Warning) != MessageResult.OK)
            return;
        else
            lineCountChecked = true;                    
    }
    //

    Lines.Add("New Line");
    RaisePropertyChanged("Lines");
}
```

It's more than likely a very stupid mistake, but I can't get it. What did I miss? Thanks

Comment: Try setting the Binding Mode to TwoWayBinding in your view.
Like <ListBox ItemSource="{Binding Lines, Mode=TwoWay}" />

Comment: @Kilazur instead of `List<T>` try using [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx). Raising `PropertyChanged` won't work because `Lines` does not change, only its items change

Comment: @Xeun Didn't work, I don't see how it would; @dkozl Yeah, that would be a bliss, but my model contains a `List<string>`. With an `ObservableCollection` it updates flawlessly indeed. I guess you can't notify a list's items change, so my only way around is to reassign the list in AddLine.

Comment: You need to raise a `CollectionChangedEvent` when you add an item rather than a propertychanged because the property Lines hasn't actually changed, the collection has

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options to make this work:

1) RaisePropertyChanged(() => Lines) => will update the whole collection
2) Use ObservableCollection instead of List so the UI can actually respond to updates

I recommend 2.

Comment: I know using ObservableCollection is the best way, but my model contain a List, what can I do about it?

Comment: In that case the mapping between the model and the view model doesn't make much sense. Create an ObservableCollection on your VM, then in the Save() method of the vm, sync the objects to the model.

Comment: Well, I did go with 2 in the end.